# How to get values from selected Fragment ArrayList instead from next Fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I create two Fragment instances at a time in ViewPager ((by default, one before the currently viewed page, and one after: Fragment f1, Fragment f2). In Fragment instacnes i have ArrayList that add values from parsed html . Problem is when i slide to selected  Fragment(n) and want to get values from  ArrayList for that selected  Fragment, ViewPager overwrite that ArrayList and references point to ArrayList from  the last page created Fragment f2 (n+1) and get values from there.

Here is PagerAdapter class:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {

private List<Fragment> fragments;
/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

Here is my class where i add Fragment instances to ViewPager:

```
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_adapter_info);

    initialisePaging();
}
private void initialisePaging() {

    Fragment f1 = new FragmentNewsReader(); // Fragment instances
    Bundle args1 = new Bundle() ;
    args1.putString("name", FragmentMainPage.ahref.get(5));
    args1.putString("title", "Info");

    f1.setArguments(args1);

    Fragment f2 = new FragmentNewsReader();
    Bundle args2 = new Bundle() ;
    args2.putString("name", FragmentMainPage.ahref.get(6));
    args2.putString("title", "Info");
    f2.setArguments(args2);

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    fragments.add(f1);
    fragments.add(f2);
            this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager_info);

    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

    pager.setCurrentItem(FragmentMainPage.broj);

}
```

Here is Fragment class:

```
 ArrayList<String> slicnitekstoviniz=new ArrayList<String>()// arraylist 
 // where i put data from parsed html

 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);       

    Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) // Parsing data from web
            .load(result)
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>()  {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                    String htmlString=result;

                    int spSLicni  = result.indexOf("<ul class=\"article-array\">");

                    int epSLicni  = result.indexOf("<!-- END .article-array -->");

                    String slicniTekstovi = result.substring(spSLicni, epSLicni);/

                    while (slicniTekstovi.indexOf("class=\"comment-icon\">") > 0) {/
                        int spHSLicni  = slicniTekstovi.indexOf("<a href=");
                        int epHSLicni  = slicniTekstovi.indexOf("/\">");

                        String ahfrefSlicni = slicniTekstovi.substring(spHSLicni, epHSLicni);

                        ahrefSlicniniz.add(ahfrefSlicni);                              

// Here is problem when i want to use data from ahrefSlicniniz.get(0) 
// I get values from next fragment and not from selected fragment

                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                    editor.putString("string_id", ahrefSlicniniz.get(0));
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Is this your problem? You have a viewpager with 2 fragments and you also store the 2 fragments you added to the viewpager in an arraylist. When you want to do something with the fragment you take it from the arraylist and you see that the instance is different from the one in the viewpager.

Comment: No, see my edit pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a page from ViewPager, the viewPager "prepares" the pages before and after it to provide a smooth paging when you move sideways. The effect on your code is that it calls onViewCrated() on the two fragments you are using. As you are storing a String in shared preferences using the same key you have a race condition where the last callback to run is the one which gets the string stored.

A quick fix would be to add a fragment number to the key ("string_id_1" / "string_id_2") and pick up the value appropiatly.

EDIT 1

where you have:

```
Fragment f1 = new FragmentNewsReader(); // Fragment instances
    Bundle args1 = new Bundle() ;
    args1.putString("name", FragmentMainPage.ahref.get(5));
    args1.putString("title", "Info");
```

add

```
 args1.putString("my_string_id","1");
```

before

```
f1.setArguments(args1);
```

Then in your fragment's onCreate() you read the value and store it locally.

```
private String myId;

...

public void onCreate(...){
    ...
    Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            myId = args.getString("my_string_id");
        }
    ...
 }
```

And do the same for fragment 2 changing the "my_string_id" value to 2 instead of 1;

Finally, where you store and pick up teh shared preference, append the myId instance variable to the key name.

I also see some other things you should be considering.

1) If you want the callback to run everytime you visit the page, you should move it to onResume() or even better to onUserVisibilityHint(), but this last option requires more race contiditions handling.

2) Storing fragment instances in array in order to fetch them from the main activity when you need them works if you control the fragments directly with the FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager. But it works really bad if the fragments are managed by a ViewPager. The ViewPager will create new instances of your fragments behind the sceens when it thinks appropiate but it will not update your arraylist leaving you with old and not used any more instances).

3) If you only have 2 fragments it may not be an issue, but if you have more more than 3 fragments, Ion callbacks could be executed when the frament is not anymore in memory. Perhaps you could cancel the futures in onPause() in the fragment.

Comment: I cant put callback to onresume or in onUserVisibilityHint(), becouse  i want to use that metod in onCreate(). Adding a fragment number to the key would be for each instance. I dont have to separate classes, Viewpager control Fragment instances

Comment: Yes each instance should know its id so it can store/pick up the correct string. You can set it the init params.

Comment: Can you show me some example code how to do that pls?